# For each page a different meta tag

Tags: php, facebook

I'm having some troubles with the `og:` inputs on my website.
I have 1 header file, but I want different `og:` tags for each page.

I already tried to make a variable and echo that in my header, but that doesn't work.

What I'm trying to create is a fully working shareable page for Facebook, with the right image, description and title.

Comment: Google `"if current page php"`

Comment: going to need to see some code. A variable should work fine, provided its in scope